# 10px font not bold on some browsers/OS-es

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts, font-face

I am trying to have a div of 10px text with a few words in bold and italic. The font is simply just sans-serif. My problem is that it works brilliantly for me on Win 7 and I see that it works well under OS X, but on XP (I think when Cleartype is not enabled), it doesn't work. The italic works, but not the bold.

Is it happening because of Cleartype not being enabled? What can I do? Start using a @font-face, which renders well? I hoped that a system default sans-serif would at least have bold in 10px size.

Here is the page in quiestion:
http://asztal.brainhurt.net/asztal.php

Comment: Looks OK in IE8 on Windows XP with and without Cleartype here. I would check which font your Windows installation is mapping the "default" sans-serif to: that could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font styles aren't up to you, they are up to the browser.  Fonts are rendered differently on different systems, especially when you get down into the smaller versions.

There isn't anything you can do about this, besides experiment with different fonts.

I recommend using http://www.typetester.org/ to assist you.

Comment: I mean I would just like to use bold in a paragraph! Is it not possible in 2011?

Comment: Of course it is possible, but you misunderstand the concept of websites.  They are rendered differently from system to system.  It is up to the browser, and you have given it some leeway by simply choosing sans-serif as well.  All you can do is make suggestions.  It is up to the browser to actually use them.  Again, follow my suggestion and experiment until you get an acceptable result.

Comment: @zsero Not anymore in 2011 that it was at the time XP SP3 came out. As the answer suggests, if it doesn't work, use another font for your bold styles.

Comment: http://www.typetester.org/ cannot help, as I'm still using my own computer. But you're right, it's because how XP handles non-Cleartype display of fonts. I've found out that for Arial the smallest size it can show bold in any application under XP is 8pt, for Verdana it's 7pt. Is it a bad idea to use pt in css?

Comment: @zsero, the generally accepted best practice is to use em.  When using em's for font size, everything is relative.  This place nicely with zooming, and also gives you a nice structure for font sizes.  The only time you should specify a pixel size is when the text needs to be relative to an image or something (but you can specify images in em too!).  Point sizes are for print, and are carried over to web as a convenience.